# Как передать не-JSON массив на сервер?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, json

Всем привет! У меня такой вопрос есть. Имеется массив вида:

```
arr[0][0]='name';
arr[0][1]='John';
arr[1][0]='surn';
arr[1][1]='Smith';
...
```

Т.е. в ячейке `0` хранится название поля, а в `1` его значение.
Нужно передать его через `AJAX`. Но при отправке на сервер он говорит массив `undefined`:

```
Data Saved: Array
(
    [undefined] => undefined
)
```

В коде (документации) он выглядит так:

```
data: { name: "John", surn: "Smith", ... },
```

но я пытался передать напрямую:

```
data: arr,
```

Есть у кого-нибудь идея как передать такой массив на сервер? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c помощью функции js [join](http://javascript.ru/Array/join) склеить массив в строку по правилу "ключ1=значение1,ключ2=значение2". И передать на сервер строку. 
Затем с помощью php функции explode распарсить сначала пары ключ=значение, а затем распарсить полученные строки на ключи и значения.

Comment: А если среди параметров встретится ","?? Я этот вариант тоже рассматривал..

Comment: используйте для разделителя любой другой символ, например "|". 
Главное определиться что может быть в массиве, а подобрать разделитель не должно быть проблемой, можно использовать сочетание символов, все что угодно

Comment: @Barton, "|" тоже занято :-( Хотя, погодите, "$" кажется свободен.. Все нашел выход.. Ан-нет еще один свободный разделитель требуется (для коротких массивов).. Короче, пошел я искать свободный символ. (вот проблему нашел себе :)))

Comment: Идиотизм, честное слово. Чем не угодил json?? Видимо на стороне сервера как-то неверно принимаете данные. Символы какие-то искать.. Жуть)

Comment: Была когда-то такая проблема, запамятовал правда какая версия php была, вроде как 5.1, точно не помню, хостинг древний, софт тоже. json поддержки попросту небыло, вот и приходилось извращаться с массивами и строками

Comment: Скачать парсер с офф. сайта JSON'a я так понимаю религия не позволяла?

Вообще - [вот одно из многих элементарно нагугливаемых решений](http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps)